# Styling an .IntegerField() to make it a star-rating system?

Tags: python, css, django

My ultimate end-goal is to get a 5-star rating system going for my website in Django. I am approaching it with a form that is linked to my model.

Here's the model for my review:

```
class review(models.Model):
ONE_TO_FIVE_RATING_CHOICES = (
    (1, '1'),
    (2, '2'),
    (3, '3'),
    (4, '4'),
    (5, '5'),
)
BOOK_RATING_CHOICES = (
    (1, '$'),
    (2, '$$'),
    (3, '$$$'),
    (4, '$$$$'),

)
ATTENDANCE_RATING_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Not Required'),
    (2, 'Required'),


)
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=0)
course = models.ForeignKey(listing)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default=None)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
review_content = models.TextField()
difficulty_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=ONE_TO_FIVE_RATING_CHOICES)
workload_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=ONE_TO_FIVE_RATING_CHOICES)
book_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=BOOK_RATING_CHOICES)
attendance_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=ATTENDANCE_RATING_CHOICES)
```

And here's the form:

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = review
    fields = [

    'difficulty_rating',
    'workload_rating',
    'book_rating',
    'attendance_rating',
    'title',
    'review_content',



    ]
```

My question is, how do I style this with CSS? I want to transform this into radio inputs that I can then cover with star icons (from FontAwesome) and still retain the functionality of being able to send these inputs to my database.

Is there an easy way? Or is this a difficult thing?

Comment: Even if you really want to implement your own, this may help: https://github.com/wildfish/django-star-ratings

Comment: I've looked into that, truth is, I'm very new to Django/Python and couldn't figure out how to implement it. I've installed it just fine, but when it comes to using it, I get this error: "Invalid block tag on line 33: 'ratings', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

This error comes right after putting {% ratings object %} in my template. I'm not too sure how to go about making this work.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include `{% load ratings %}` at the top of the template? That's what tells the template engine that the ratings application's template tags exist.

Comment: Nope, it's there. I put it at the top of my base.html which gave me the error stated above, but if I put it on my "class_page.html" it gives me "'str' object has no attribute '_meta'" error.

edit: nevermind, I had to put {% ratings instance %} instead and now it works! Just have to figure out the rest of the star-rating system and how to make it work with my database

Comment: It's possible that it won't work for you, because it seems to link a model to a rating, and you want to link several fields of a model. It can help you with the implementation though, particularly if you look at the widget.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, all you have to do can be broken down into following steps:

1. Hide the radio fields by setting CSS property `display: none;`.
2. Show stars in place of radio fields.
3. Set a rating value on each star. E.g. The first star should hold a rating value of 1, the second star should have a value of 2, and so on.
4. Set a target value to the name of the corresponding radio field.
5. When a user clicks a star, take its rating value and check the corresponding target radio field using JavaScript.

---

#### [SEE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/e7hL3r7n/4/).

#### HTML:

First important thing to note is that you've to set rating value and a target radio input on every star. That way, if a star is clicked, you take it's rating value and check the target radio input.

So, a star should look like this:

```
<i class="rating-star" data-rating="1" data-target="difficulty_rating"></i>
```

If you create a star for `workload_rating`, you have to change it's `data-target` value:

```
<i class="rating-star" data-rating="1" data-target="workload_rating"></i>
```

You can repeat it for other rating fields.

Example code for stars (copy and paste the following code where you want to display the stars):

```html
<!-- Stars for difficulty_rating -->
<div class="rating">
    <!-- The stars must be in reverse order of rating value -->
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="5" data-target="difficulty_rating"></i>
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="4" data-target="difficulty_rating"></i>
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="3" data-target="difficulty_rating"></i>
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="2" data-target="difficulty_rating"></i>
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="1" data-target="difficulty_rating"></i>
</div>

<!-- Stars for workload_rating -->
<div class="rating">
    <!-- The stars must be in reverse order of rating value -->
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="5" data-target="workload_rating"></i>
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="4" data-target="workload_rating"></i>
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="3" data-target="workload_rating"></i>
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="2" data-target="workload_rating"></i>
    <i class="rating-star" data-rating="1" data-target="workload_rating"></i>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

Add this to your CSS stylesheet:

```css
.rating {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFCA00;
  font-style: normal;
}

.rating-star {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

.rating-star:after {
  position: relative;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f006';
}

.rating-star.checked ~ .rating-star:after,
.rating-star.checked:after {
  content: '\f005';
}

.rating:hover .rating-star:after {
  content: '\f006';
}

.rating-star:hover ~ .rating-star:after,
.rating-star:hover:after {
  content: '\f005' !important;
}
```

#### JavaScript:

I've used [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to make the JavaScript part easier.

Insert the following code before the `</body>` tag ends in your template:

```html
<!-- Include jquery -->
<!-- this requires an internet connection. but you can download jquery and put it in your static folder and link it from there -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- JS code for updating rating values -->
<script>
    $('.rating-star').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parents('.rating').find('.rating-star').removeClass('checked'); // uncheck previously checked star

        $(this).addClass('checked'); // check currently selected star

        var ratingValue = $(this).attr('data-rating'); // get rating value
        var ratingTarget = $(this).attr('data-target');

        // set the rating value to corresponding target radio input
        $('input[name="' + ratingTarget + '"][value="' + ratingValue + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment! so this works, but this isn't linked to my model in any way, is it not? Ideally, I'd like whatever inputs the user chooses to be recorded as data for the specific instance of my model, so that I can then display an average of these ratings on that same page. How would I do that?

because from my understanding, this is just creating a whole new rating-system, and so far, based on the code I don't see it being linked to my model in any way

Comment: @dmandres Have you created a django form yet? All you have to do is display that form in your templates and hide the inputs/ I thought you had implemented all that. If not, well, you've got to read django docs about how to link a form to model and save the data.

Comment: I have a form already set up! But to display that form in my templates I use {{ form.as_p }}. Which locks me into the default styling of said form, I don't see how I can hide the inputs/replace them with stars?